# "Switch nuget and project references" in Rider

Tags: reference, nuget, jetbrains-ide, rider

There is a tool for Visual Studio called "Switch nuget and project references" and it works fine. I'm looking for the same for JetBrains Rider IDE.

Do you know is there any tool alternative for Rider or maybe it has such functionality that I don't know about that will also give me ability to change references between local and nuget packages?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-18325 is the issue link :)